# Retrieve multiple checkbox values from jsp in the spring controller class

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In my table, I've a row with checkbox which tells the controller whether that particular row of the table has to be included or no. The check box does not have relation with other rows. I tried adding it in the following way :

```
<form:form id="fee" method="post" modelAttribute="clientForm" commandName = "clientForm" 
action="<%= request.getContextPath().toString()%>/addFee.do">

    <TABLE>
            <tr>
                <c:forEach var="type" items="${clientInfo}" varStatus="status">
                    <td><form:checkbox class="editable${ifeeCount}" path="includeFeeValue" value="false"/> </td>
                        <td>feeType<c:out value = "${status.index}"/></td>
                        <td>Source Fee<c:out value = "${status.index}"/></td>
                        <td><form:input class="editable${ifeeCount}" disabled="true" path="overriddenFee" /></td>
                            <td><form:errors path="overriddenFee" cssClass="error" /></td>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
    </TABLE>
```

And in my form, I've a list `private ArrayList<String> includeFeeValue;`

And i'm trying to retrieve this in the spring controller class as follows :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addFee.do",method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected @ResponseBody ModelAndView selectValues(@ModelAttribute("clientForm") PaswFeeMaintenanceForm MyMaintForm ) throws Exception {

    for(int i=0;i<MyMaintForm.getIncludeFeeValue().size();i++){
        System.out.println("Checkbox : "+MyMaintForm.getIncludeFeeValue().get(i)+ " of "+i);
    }
}
```

Once I submit my form, it throws `null pointer exception` in here : `MyMaintForm.getIncludeFeeValue().size()` .

Could you tell me what's missing here?

Comment: Possibly `getIncludeFeeValue()` is returning `null`

Comment: @JaveDeveloper `getIncludeFeeValue()` is `null` for sure, maybe `disabled="true"` is not binding the value, try removing this and test again.

Comment: I tried after removing diabled=true. It's still the same.Null pointer exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `disabled='true'` and it will work. I faced the same problem with my textfield with property disabled as true.

And also use `private String[] includeFeeValue` instead of `List`.

Comment: I tried after removing diabled=true. It's still the same.Null pointer exception

Comment: Post your full spring form please.

Comment: Updated answer. Can you please use array instead of List and check?

Comment: But the checkbox is within the for each loop. I've multiple entries and on click of submit I need the check box values of all the rows.

Comment: You can get that in Array as well. Though I'm not sure about it, but it worth a try.

Comment: Got the value after changing to String array and by passing the index of the loop in the value of the checkbox field.

Answer (score 0):

As your checkbox is disabled, ans disabled elements values never flow to controller or Servlet. I advise you to remove a disabled attribute. I hope so it will work.

Comment: I tried after removing diabled=true. It's still the same.Null pointer exception